# Create JSON from an array of int

Tags: python, json, django

I have a django model called `ServiceSubCategory` and I want to create a JSON list of its primary key values using Python.

I have tried this:

```
idDic=[obj.as_json for obj in ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)]
```

But I'm getting this error:

> `int` object has no attribute `as_json`

I'm doing this because I'm gonna append another JSON to this later.

So how could I create a JSON out of my models primery Keys?

**Update**

I tried

```
id_json = json.dumps(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True))
```

And I'm getting a new error:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is not JSON serializable

And this is the traceback:

> Traceback: File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/var/www/html/salimi/salimi/views.py" in service
>     61.     idDic=json.dumps(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True))
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py" in dumps
>     243.         return _default_encoder.encode(obj) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in encode
>     207.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
>     270.         return _iterencode(o, 0) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in default
>     184.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /service/1/ Exception Value: [1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import json
json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)))
```

`values_list` returns an instance of `django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet` which does not have a default JSON serializer (it's just a QuerySet, no database request is made so far). However, you can transform it into a list object before.

```
import json
values_list_object = ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
list_object = list(values_list) # querying the database
json.dumps(list_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write the following:

```
import json

id_json = json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)))
```

Comment: now I'm getting `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

It looks like `ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)` might return a generator. In that case you can consume the generator using `list()`:

```
import json
json.dumps(list(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)))
```

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
import json
json.dumps(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Since `ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list` is already a list it can be dumped directly to JSON. There is no need to use a list comprehension.

Comment: now I'm getting `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @AlexJolig: Could you post the traceback for that error, and the output of `repr(ServiceSubCategory.objects.values_list)`. Also, are you after a list of JSON strings, or the list converted to JSON (as this answer attempts)?

Comment: Updated the answer with traceback and I guess it would be better if I get the JSON values as string

Comment: @Selcuk: well thanks for that. It would have been nice if you could have rolled it back to the most recent edit.

Comment: @mhawke Sorry, your last edit wasn't there when I rolled it back. Must be a clash.

Comment: @Selcuk: No problem.  It might have been work in progress. Anyway, we had basically identical answers so it's easy to see why you might edit the wrong one.... and [blacklwhite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35521874/21945) figured it out anyway.